# How to avoid the float display mistake in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Say you have some numbers to show like this:

Using 'toFixed' can simply make it better but it's not what expected. Is there any easy way to output the numbers as expected in this snippet below?

Thanks,

```js
$('body').append('<p>Do nothing:</p>');

var a = 100-68.7;
$('body').append('<p>' + a + '</p>');



var b = 100-68.52;
$('body').append('<p>' + b + '</p>');


var c = 100-6;
$('body').append('<p>' + c + '</p>');



$('body').append('<hr>');

$('body').append('<p>Using toFixed:</p>');

var a1 = 100-68.7;
$('body').append('<p>' + a1.toFixed(2) + '</p>');



var b1 = 100-68.52;
$('body').append('<p>' + b1.toFixed(2) + '</p>');


var c1 = 100-6;
$('body').append('<p>' + c1.toFixed(2) + '</p>');





$('body').append('<hr>');

$('body').append('<p>Expected Result:</p>');

$('body').append('<p>31.3</p>');
$('body').append('<p>31.48</p>');
$('body').append('<p>94</p>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you just don’t like trailing zeros in the decimal part, then you can simply trim them off after calling toFixed. And to make the overall code more concise, you can make that into a little function of its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap your values in "parseFloat"

```js
$('body').append('<hr>');

$('body').append('<p>Using toFixed:</p>');

var a1 = 100-68.7;
$('body').append('<p>' + parseFloat(a1.toFixed(2)) + '</p>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: try enter `parseFloat(1-4.6)` in the console.

Comment: Nice try by using parseFloat+toFixed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('body').append('<p>Do nothing:</p>');

var a = 100-68.7;
$('body').append('<p>' + a + '</p>');



var b = 100-68.52;
$('body').append('<p>' + b + '</p>');


var c = 100-6;
$('body').append('<p>' + c + '</p>');



$('body').append('<hr>');

$('body').append('<p>Using toFixed:</p>');

var a1 = 100-68.7;
$('body').append('<p>' + a1.toFixed(2).replace(/\.?0+$/, '') + '</p>');



var b1 = 100-68.52;
$('body').append('<p>' + b1.toFixed(2).replace(/\.?0+$/, '') + '</p>');


var c1 = 100-6;
$('body').append('<p>' + c1.toFixed(2).replace(/\.?0+$/, '') + '</p>');





$('body').append('<hr>');

$('body').append('<p>Expected Result:</p>');

$('body').append('<p>31.3</p>');
$('body').append('<p>31.48</p>');
$('body').append('<p>94</p>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**Solution**

Using replace `0` it will done. You can see. may it will be helpful to you

**Update**

You can check your `Using toFixed:`

Answer (score 0):

use `parseFloat` around the string returned by `toFixed(2)`

```js
var a1 = 100-68.7;
$('body').append('<p>' + parseFloat(a1.toFixed(2)) + '</p>');



var b1 = 100-68.52;
$('body').append('<p>' + parseFloat(b1.toFixed(2) )+ '</p>');


var c1 = 100-6;
$('body').append('<p>' + parseFloat(c1.toFixed(2)) + '</p>');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `parseFloat()` just like this:

```
var numbers = 31.480000000000004; //this will be the numbers 
    numbers = numbers.toFixed(2);
    console.log(parseFloat(numbers ));
```

By this you can fixed to 2 only then you can now parse it float.

This should be work.

Answer (score 0):

There's always [`Number.toLocaleString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) which makes for readable code.

```js
const a = 100 - 68.7,
      b = 100 - 68.52,
      c = 100 - 6;

const format = n => n.toLocaleString('en', {
    maximumFractionDigits: 2,
    useGrouping: false
});

console.log([a, b, c].map(format));
```